# Angular date time pipe unit test

Tags: angular, jasmine, timezone

We have a simple date time pipe in Angular that returns the given timestamp with the correct format:

`formatDate(new Date(date), 'd.M.yyyy HH:mm', 'en-US');`

I'm having issues when unit testing this, as the tests might run in different timezones and the expected output should stay the same. I'm not sure if should replace the `new Date()` with something else or can the tests somehow always run in the same timezone?

`expect(pipe.transform('2023-01-20T10:34:10.811')).toEqual('20.1.2023 10:34');`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mockDate(initialDate)` method of [Clock](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/Clock.html) class

> Jasmine's mock clock is used when testing time-dependent code.

The `new Date()` will always return the `initialDate` no matter what timezone the test run.

E.g.

```js
describe('76376438', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const clock = jasmine.clock();
    clock.install()

    const baseTime = new Date('2023-01-20T10:34:10.811');
    clock.mockDate(baseTime)

    const now = new Date().getTime();
    expect(now).toEqual(baseTime.getTime())
  })
})
```

```bash
Randomized with seed 15816
Started

Executing 1 defined specs...
Running in random order... (seed: 15816)

Test Suites & Specs:

1. 76376438
   ✔ should pass (15ms)


1 spec, 0 failures
Finished in 0.044 seconds
Randomized with seed 15816 (jasmine --random=true --seed=15816)


>> Done!


Summary:

  Passed
Suites:  1 of 1
Specs:   1 of 1
Expects: 2 (0 failures)
Finished in 0.044 seconds
```